# Javascript reverse array of numbers and subtract 2, then 1, then 0 then add 1, add 2 etc

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the awful title.  I've crashed enough browsers and asking for help.

Here's the specific problem I'm trying to solve.

Create a function called 'reversedLooper' that when passed an array will loop through it backwards and subtract 2 from the last element, 1 from the second to last, 0 from to the third to last, add one to the fourth to last, add 2 to the fifth to last, etc. until it reaches the front of the array.  Return the list when you are done

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't a code writing service....the idea is for you to show the code you are having problems with so people can help resolve those problems

Comment: First - you should always post code you have tried so we can see where you made a mistake or need assistance. :-) Second, you should be able to get the length of the array (array.length), do a normal FOR loop from 0 to N. Then just have a variable that reverses that. So if you do FOR( var i=0; i<N; i++ ){ then you have var j = N-i; J = reverse. Now you know where you are in the array (ie: i) and what you are working with (ie: j).

Comment: Apologies.  Here's what I've tried.  I know this only reversed the array and doesn't actually manipulate the values of indices.  I tried doing a nested for loop to adjust the amount to subtract/add but kept crashing the browser.

function reversedLooper(array) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
    newArray.push(i);
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(reversedLooper([1, 2, 3, 4]));

Comment: Have you tried working with Immutable.js? I know with Immutable you could do something like this: `var list = Immutable.List([1,2,3]); var reversedList = list.reverse()`. That would get you the reversed list to work with, then you could map the list and apply the logic you need to based on the index in the list. Then, after you're done, call reverse again and call `toJS()` and you have things back out. I'll put together a fiddle to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with [`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
myArray.map(function(item, index, arr) {
  return item + arr.length - index - 3;
});
```

Comment: The expression that I had in mind was `item - (2 - (arr.length - 1 - index))`. You can see that that distributing the -1s produces `item + arr.length - index -3`. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter, more concise version.

```
function reversedLooper(arr){
  var increaseBy = -2;
  for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    arr[i] += increaseBy;
    increaseBy++
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's real ugly, but appears to satisfy the test cases.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
function reversedLooper(array) {
    var newArray = [];
    var n = -3;
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      n++;
        if (array[i] === array.length) {
            newArray.push(array[i] - 2);
        }
        else if (array[i] === array.length - 1) {
            newArray.push(array[i] - 1);
        }
        else if (array[i] === array.length - 2) {
            newArray.push(array[i]);
        }
        else {
            newArray.push(array[i] + n)
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
console.log(reversedLooper(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on my comment, I will use the new fiddle plug in to make something to show you here.

```js
let list = Immutable.List.of(1,2,3,4,5)

function createListOperationsMapping(list) {
  // Maybe consider dynamically creating a mapping of methods to indexes
  // If you return a Map from this that is something like:
  /*
   Map({
     0: (item) => item - 2,
     1: (item) => item - 1,
     // since there's a case where you subtract 0, so no change
     2: (item) => item,
     3: (item) => item + 1,
     4: (item) => item + 2,
     5: (item) => item + 3,
     // etc...
   })
   
   */
  // This would allow you to map the reversedList and based on the index you could just  
  // call the method from the map...
  // Like this (where the map from above ^^ is called listOperationMap)
  /*
  
    var mutatedReversedList = reversedList.map((item, index) => {
      return listOperationMap[index](item);
    })

   Notice I used the word "mutated" here. If you use Immutable, 
   you're actually returning a copy with updates rather than mutating, 
   but I wanted to make it clear that the result of mapping the 
   Immutable List will be a new Immutable List - not the mutated 
   previous list. Also, if you choose to work with Immutable, remember 
   you will need to set new variables for return values of updates to 
   the Immutable data structures.
  
   */
}

let reversedList = list.reverse() 

let reversedListSize = reversedList.size

let newList = reversedList.map((listItem, index) => {
  // Do stuff in here
})

console.log(list.toJS())
console.log(reversedList.toJS())
console.log(reversedListSize)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.7.6/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Since your question was a bit vague, I'm basically just throwing out some ideas based on what there was to work with. Hopefully this is useful in at least starting to explore how you might approach the problem you are trying to solve.

Either way, I recommend taking a look at Immutable.js.

PS: If you click on "Run code snippet", then crack open your dev tools and the console.log(s) will show up in your console.